# How to add/replace inner object inside JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ecmascript-6

I have a JavaScript array with the form of

```
const Rooms = [{
        name:"Science",
        students:[
            {user:"Tom",emotion:"Happy"},
            {user:"Marry",emotion:"Angry"},
            {user:"Adam",emotion:"Happy"}]
    },{
        name:"Maths",
        students:[
        {user:"Stewie",emotion:"Angry"},
            {user:"Cleavland",emotion:"Angry"},
            {user:"Meg",emotion:"Happy"},
            {user:"Peter",emotion:"Angry"},
            {user:"Chris",emotion:"Happy"}]
    },{
        name:"History",
        students:[
            {user:"Monica",emotion:"Angry"},
            {user:"Chandler",emotion:"Happy"},
            {user:"Joe",emotion:"Happy"},
            {user:"Ross",emotion:"Angry"}]
    }];
```

I need to find a room by name and add/replace it by student when needed. It means I should be able to find the Room (Maths) and add/update student. If student is already there then its emotion should be changed.

This is the code that I tried but it didn't replace the existing  student.

```
Rooms.forEach((e)=>{if(e.name === "Science"){
    e.students.push({user:"Tom",emotion:"Surprised"});
}});
```

How can I search for a particular json and change the existing student or add a new student data (if student is not present)?

Comment: you can do it easily with [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/)

Comment: @GaurangGhinaiya There's absolutely no need for an external library. ES6 has enough methods to do this easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use find in the array of the students:

For instance, to finding "Tom" and updating it:

```
Rooms.forEach((e)=>{
  if(e.name === "Science"){
   const tom = e.students.find((student) => student.user === "Tom");
   if (!tom)       
      e.students.push({user:"Tom",emotion:"Surprised"});
   else
      tom.emotion = "Surprised";
  }
});
```

Note: you may also be using find for finding the room instead of using forEach:

```
const e = Rooms.find((room) => room.name === "Science");
if (e) {
  const tom = e.students.find((student) => student.user === "Tom");
  if (!tom)       
     e.students.push({user:"Tom",emotion:"Surprised"});
  else
     tom.emotion = "Surprised";
  }
}
```